# Make the compiler deduce the parameter of a function before compilation

Tags: c++, function, templates, fpga

Here is an example of my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//template<std::size_t A> <-- Tried to solve the problem by using template
void func1(const int power){
    const int length = 1 << power;
    int twoDArrayA[length][length];

    for (int j = 0; j < power; j++)
    {
        /* Code */
    }
}

int main() {
    func1(4);
    func1(3);
    func1(2);
}
```

I wonder if I could somehow allow the compiler to deduce parameter **power** in func1 before it compiles. So instead of compiles one function, it compiles 4 functions in the format of func1 with different **power** value.

The reason for this is because I would like to use Vitis HLS to unroll the loop and partition the matrix so that it could be implemented onto a FPGA, where a variable-length loop or array cannot work properly.

Comment: That your compiler is letting you get away with `int twoDArrayA[length][length];` doesn't make it legal code. Use `std::vector`

Comment: Why didn't the template solution work?

Comment: @lakeweb It's legal if `length` is known at compile time.

Comment: @PaulSanders yes, but that is not the case in *this* code, because `power` is not a compile-time constant, its value is not known until runtime.

Comment: Does the tag `compiler-construction` apply. I get that when the question was asked you did not know but the answers seem to imply there are other means and so the tag is no longer necessary.

Comment: @lakeweb std::vector will make it nearly impossible to synthesize efficiently, so must be a static array of a maximum allowed size (or derived from a template argumnet)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, yes, but the OP _intends_ it to be, he just muffed the syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with a template, but you've got the wrong syntax.  It should be:

```
template<std::size_t power>
void func1(){
    const std::size_t length = 1 << power;
    int twoDArrayA[length][length];
    ...
}

int main() {
    func1<4>();
    ...
}
```

Note that your variable length array (VLA) is legal C++ if `length` is a compile-time constant (as it is here).  Nevertheless, `std::array` would be a better bet.

PS: Thanks for telling us *why* you want to do this.  That was a nice touch.

Comment: If `length` is a compile-time constant, it's not really a VLA, is it?

Comment: @NathanPierson Sure.  I put that bit in because of lakeweb's comment above.